# How do I configure Bird to use OSPF?

Tags: ospf, anycast, gns3, bird

I'm configuring a network with the following topology:

[image: network]

What I need to do is to provide a service that is available by Anycast and that is announced by OSPF. I managed to configure OSPF on the routers. I also created a dummy interface with the same IP in both servers. But now I'm not sure how to configure Bird on the servers so the Client can acess them via the Anycast IP. I'm simulating the network on GNS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the servers you could try using this configuration:

```
router id x.x.x.x; 

protocol device {
}

protocol kernel {
        metric 64;      # Use explicit kernel route metric to avoid collisions
                        # with non-BIRD routes in the kernel routing table
        import none;
        export all;     # Actually insert routes into the kernel routing table
}

protocol static {
        import all;
}

protocol ospf myOSPF {
        import all;
        export all;

    area 0 {
        interface "Your dummy interface name" {
               cost 5;
               type broadcast;
               hello 5; retransmit 2; wait 10; dead 20;
               authentication cryptographic; password "XXXX";
         };
     };
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It gives me an error, I can't start Bird. There is a syntax error somewhere

Comment: I forgot to add a ";" after router id, I have edited the post with the missing semicolon

Comment: I'm still not able to ping the dummy interface from the client, I set the router id to 192.168.2.1 and interface name to dummy0. The dummy 0 IP is 1.1.1.1. This is for the server located below the client. Do I need to configure anything in the main router? The only thing I did in the router was add all the networks to the backbone area.

Comment: You need to announce the subnet from the router as well. And as I recall you can only announce /24 subnets.




`
filter ospf_in_test {
    if net = x.x.x.x/24 then accept;
    reject;
}

filter ospf_out_test {
    reject;
}
`

And then the ospf configuration